# Can we use Angular translate different languages for different components/modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate to change the language of my application.
My application has different languages only for testing and it is sepperated in different modules, Lazy loading.

So I have 2 variables of language.
1 is for the CV of the person which only there the text will be changed depends on the language it is selected.
2 it is for all other components and modules.

But the actual problem it is that if I use translate.use(cvLanguage) then it is translating all the application.
Same happens with the Main components which are out of this module.

I tried to use isolate in Translate Module but it is not working.

This is my code.

app.module.ts

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: httpTranslateLoader,
    deps: [HttpClient],
  },
}),

export function httpTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

And this is the user.module.

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: httpTranslateLoader
  },
  isolate: true
}),
export function httpTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

I tried to seperate in modules and isolate the translate but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but you can try with separate TranslateModule for each separate modules. **Don't add it to AppModule.**